# Appending to a string in bash w/o prefixing extra whitespace

Tags: bash

I have a script, named `replace.run`, called in a manner akin to:

```
$ replace.run 10
```

This file contains:

```
char="pre case\ntext xskey=001 \nREADY\n"
i=2
while [ $i -le $1 ]; do
char="$char pre case\ntext xskey=00$i \nREADY\n"
i=$((i+1))
done
```

The problem is that

```
$char=pre case\ntext xskey=001 \nREADY\n pre case\ntext xskey=002 \nREADY\n pre case\ntext xskey=003 \nREADY\n pre case\ntext xskey=004 \nREADY\n pre case\ntext xskey=005 \nREADY\n pre case\ntext xskey=006 \nREADY\n pre case\ntext xskey=007 \nREADY\n pre case\ntext xskey=008 \nREADY\n pre case\ntext xskey=009 \nREADY\n pre case\ntext xskey=0010 \nREADY\n
```

As you can see there is a space between `READY\n` and `pre case`. This space is unwanted. Any help getting rid of it would be most welcome.
I tried something like

```
echo $char|sed 's/ pre case/pre case/' >char
```

But that’s clearly a mess.

Comment: BTW, `"foo\nbar"` is just one line, not two, with a literal backslash and a literal `n` in it. Perhaps you mean `$'foo\nbar'`?

Comment: Also, `echo $char` is always wrong -- it string-splits and glob-expands contents into individual items then put on `echo`'s command line, so the difference between different kinds of whitespace is lost. `echo "$char"`, or -- better -- `printf '%s' "$char"` [if you don't want a trailing newline] or `printf '%s\n' "$char"` [if you do] won't have this issue.

Comment: Why `"$char pre"` and not `"${char}pre"`, if you don't want that space?

Comment: THX solved! I'm sorry for such a lame problem! 
Again THX and also THX for the info

Comment: Hopefully my edits (intended to improve clarity of the question) faithfully respect your intent; please let me know if otherwise. And if my answer solved your problem, consider clicking the checkbox alongside it.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the reason you have this extra space is the following ambiguity:

```
# BUG: this expands $charpre instead of $char
char="$charpre case\ntext xskey=00$i \nREADY\n"
```

There are a few ways to avoid this:

```
# FIX: use ${} to allow the new "pre" to be immediately after prior content
char="${char}pre case\ntext xskey=00$i \nREADY\n"
```

...or...

```
# FIX: use += to append without expanding old content
char+="pre case\ntext xskey=00$i \nREADY\n"
```

---

That said, an altogether different approach might make more sense:

```
lines=( )
for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++)); do
  printf -v xskey '%03d' "$i" # format as 0-padded 3-digit value
  lines+=( "precase" "text xskey=$xskey" "READY" )
done

printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}"
```

This collects your lines in an *array*, not a single string, giving you more detailed control. It also ensures that when your counter goes over 9, you get `text ksey=010`, not `text xskey=0010`.

---

If you really want `\n`s instead of newlines, you could make that change by just changing the last line:

```
# ...if you want to put "\n" strings, not literal newlines, in output:
printf '%s\\n' "${lines[@]}"
```

Comment: Good to see an answer that actually suggest a different approach instead of monkey patching +1

Answer (score 0):

`>` redirect to a file. So you now got a file called `char`.

You can use command substitutions to capture the output of a command in a variable:

```
char=$(sed 's/pre case/precase/' <<< "$char")
```

Always remember to put double quotes around variable expansions, `"$char"` instead of `$char`

You don't need to use sed at all though:

```
char="${char/pre case/precase}"
```

BTW `\n` is not a newline in bash strings. You can use the following c string syntax `$'...'`. Which will use C escape sequences, eg:

```
% echo "a\nb"
a\nb
% echo $'a\nb'
a
b
```

Comment: I appreciate allot your answer..
Both option are simple and clear, but I need to clear the space in:

READY\n pre   ----->       READY\npre

And the "\n" may be causing some trouble with sed? I sort of need that \n for other reasons... again THX